# Rendering chunks of HTML

Tags: android, android-layout

I receive chunks of HTML containing `b`,`i`,`img`,`hx`,`ol`,and `li` tags, which I need to render preferably without stripping tags. Additionally, I'd like to save those chunks so that the application doesn't have to download it again.

What are my options here in terms of rendering? I consider WebView a rather bold decision; besides I'm not sure whether it can cache images.

Examples please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) has cache capabilities built in through the internal class [WebSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html)

Here's a nice tutorial on how to implement it:

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/saving-the-android-webview-cache-on-the-sd-card/

Answer (score 1):

> What are my options here in terms of rendering?

For that mix of tags? You can use `WebView`. Or you may be able use `TextView`, if you write your own replacement for `Html.fromHtml()` that handles the bullets. I *think* `TextView` can render bullets [using `BulletSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BulletSpan.html), though I have not tried it. And, you would also need to have your own smarts for `<img>` tags for handling image caching.

BTW, I am assuming `hx` means `h1`, `h2`, and kin.